# Why is this showing me an error when I try to free a matrix?

Tags: c, arrays, free

When i try to compile my code , I get this error and I don't know why:

> error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘free’
>         free(A[i]);

```
void freeMatrix(int N, double *A)
{
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        free(A[i]);
free(A);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show us more of the code. For example, what is the type of `A` ?

Comment: Please listen to and fix all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough reputation to comment, hence writing as an answer.

A[i] is of type double. free() expects a pointer. did you perhaps mean to declare the function as

```
void freeMatrix(int N, double **A){
   for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      free(A[i]);
   free(A);
}
```

The question was clarified: the matrix was originally created as

```
double *A = (double *)malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
```

In this case, a single call

```
free(A);
```

is enough. In general, you should call free() exactly as often as malloc()

Comment: `free(*A);` neee, `free(A);` itself.

Comment: actually the declaration of the function is with "double *A" . And the allocation of the array is written like this "double *A = (double *)malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));"

Comment: @Pistachio in that case, you only need to call free(A). Usually, for every call to malloc() you need exactly one call to free() later

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, you are trying do deallocate a matrix (array of arrays) while passing an array as function parameter. Try the following:

```
void freeMatrix(int N, double ** A)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        free(A[i]);
    free(* A);
}
```

Comment: `free(* A);` is the same as `free(A[0]` and this code is the same as @Michael's answer..

Comment: No, it is not the same, A[0] is the first element of the array, while `free(* A);` in this case is free memory (array) that is present under address after dereferencing of pointer to pointer to A. BTW. I was first with the comment ;)

Comment: The `[` operator works like `a[b]` is equal to `*(a + b)`. In case of `A[0]` it is equal to `*(A + 0)` which is equal to `*A`. See [C11 6.5.2.1p2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2). It is the same. Your code has undefined behavior, as you double free the address obtained with `A[0]` or `*A` (or `0[A]`).